# Continue playing a Video's audio when device is locked

Tags: android, android-videoview

In my Android app I want to have a video, which continues playing the audio when the user locks the device. I can't seem to find an answer to this problem.

I tried setting the WakeMode for a MediaPlayer instance but once I add the second line the Video won't play at all.

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.demovideo);
        mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

I also tried using a VideoView, but didn't get far either.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this way to stop video

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mp.stop();
}
```

Comment: I want the opposite, the audio should continue playing when the device is locked

Comment: you can't play video while the phone is locked

Comment: Is there really no way/workaround/framework? Because there seem to be some apps on the Play store that offer this feature

Comment: can you share link of that app also i had done some research on this function

Comment: I might have been wrong here, they offer background audio but I guess that doesn't apply to locking the device. I can't believe no one else seems to need this function though